# Как добавить ScrollPane к TextArea Когда Layout(null). Надо добавить ScrollPane к inputText и outputText

Tags: java, swing, layout, jscrollpane

```
public class SimpleGUI extends JFrame {
// BUTTONS
private JButton DecriptButton = new JButton("Decript");
private JButton IncriptButton = new JButton("Incript");
private JButton ReadText = new JButton("File Info");
private JButton SetIncText = new JButton("Set Text");
private JButton SetDecText = new JButton("Set Text");

//TEXT FIELDS
private JTextArea inputText = new JTextArea(2,2);
private JTextArea outputText = new JTextArea(8,8);
private JTextField keyA = new JTextField("", 1);
private JTextField keyB = new JTextField("", 1);

//LABELS
private JLabel labelInput = new JLabel("Uncripted text:");
private JLabel labelOutput = new JLabel("Incripted text:");
private JLabel labelB = new JLabel("Key B:");
private JLabel labelA = new JLabel("Key A:");
private JLabel authorLabel = new JLabel("created by Zakhar Okrutyi 2019");

//SEPARATORS
private JSeparator inputTextSep = new JSeparator();
private JSeparator outputTextSep = new JSeparator();
private JSeparator keyATextSep = new JSeparator();
private JSeparator keyBTextSep = new JSeparator();

JScrollPane incriptScroll;

//MENUS
private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

AniButton jb;

public SimpleGUI() {

    super("Crypt");
    this.setBounds(500, 500, 600, 460);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);
    setContentPane(new BgPanel());
    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(null);



    Queue<Color> q = new LinkedList<Color>();
    generateColors(q);
    jb = new AniButton(q, this);
    jb.setBounds(this.getWidth() -150, 380, 100, 30);
    jb.setBorder(null);
    jb.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    jb.setText("Colors");
    jb.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            jb.startAnimation();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            jb.stopAnimation();
        }
    });


    //INPUT TEXT LABEL
    labelInput.setBounds(50, 20, 300, 20);
    labelInput.setFont(new Font("lucida console", Font.BOLD, 16));
    labelInput.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);


    //OUTPUT TEXT LABEL
    labelOutput.setBounds(50, 170, 300, 20);
    labelOutput.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
    labelOutput.setFont(new Font("lucida console", Font.BOLD, 16));


    //INPUT TEXT FIELD
    inputText.setBounds(50, 45, 500, 50);
    inputText.setBackground(null);
    inputText.setBorder(null);
    inputText.setLineWrap(true);
    inputText.setWrapStyleWord(false);
    inputText.setCaretPosition(0);
    inputTextSep.setBounds(50,95,500,10);
    inputTextSep.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    incriptScroll.getViewport().add(inputText);
    incriptScroll = new 

      JScrollPane(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
      JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
      incriptScroll.setBounds(550,45,20,50);

    container.add(incriptScroll);



    //OUTPUT TEXT FIELD
    outputText.setBounds(50, 195, 500, 50);
    outputText.setBackground(null);
    outputText.setBorder(null);
    outputText.setLineWrap(true);
    outputText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    outputTextSep.setBounds(50,245,500,10);
    outputTextSep.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    final JScrollPane outputScrollPane = new JScrollPane(outputText);
    container.add(outputScrollPane);


    //KEY A TEXT LABEL
    labelA.setBounds(50, 115, 100, 20);
    labelA.setFont(new Font("lucida console", Font.BOLD, 16));
    labelA.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);


    //KEY A TEXT FIELD
    keyA.setBounds(50, 135, 50, 20);
    keyA.setBackground(null);
    keyA.setBorder(null);
    keyATextSep.setBounds(50,155,50,10);
    keyATextSep.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);


    //KEY B TEXT LABEL
    labelB.setBounds(170, 115, 100, 20);
    labelB.setFont(new Font("lucida console", Font.BOLD, 16));
    labelB.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);


    //KEY B TEXT FIELD
    keyB.setBounds(170 , 135, 50, 20);
    keyB.setBackground(null);
    keyB.setBorder(null);
    keyBTextSep.setBounds(170,155,50,10);
    keyBTextSep.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);


    //AUTHOR LABEL
    authorLabel.setBounds(getWidth()/2-90,415,200,15);
    authorLabel.setFont(new Font("monospace",Font.BOLD,10));
    authorLabel.setForeground(Color.GRAY);

     //SET DEC TEXT BUTTON
    SetDecText.setBounds(getWidth() - 125,250,80,30);
    SetDecText.setBorder(null);
    SetDecText.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

    //SET INC TEXT BUTTON
    SetIncText.setBounds(getWidth() - 125,100,80,30);
    SetIncText.setBorder(null);
    SetIncText.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);


    //DECRIPTION BUTTON
    DecriptButton.setBounds(50, 380, 100, 30);
    DecriptButton.setBorder(null);
    DecriptButton.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);


    //INCRIPTION BUTTON
    IncriptButton.setBounds(170, 380, 100, 30);
    IncriptButton.setBorder(null);
    IncriptButton.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);


    //FILE READ BUTTON
    ReadText.setBounds( 290, 380, 100, 30);
    ReadText.setBorder(null);
    ReadText.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);


    //COMPONENTS ADDING
    container.add(inputTextSep);
    container.add(outputTextSep);
    container.add(keyATextSep);
    container.add(keyBTextSep);

    container.add(labelInput);

    container.add(inputText);

    container.add(labelOutput);
    container.add(outputText);

    container.add(labelA);
    container.add(keyA);

    container.add(labelB);
    container.add(keyB);

    container.add(authorLabel);

    container.add(ReadText);
    container.add(SetIncText);
    container.add(SetDecText);
    container.add(DecriptButton);
    container.add(IncriptButton);
    container.add(ReadText);
    //        container.add(jb);
    container.add(menuBar);

    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    JMenu file = new JMenu("Info");
    menuBar.add(file);
    JMenuItem Author = new JMenuItem("Author");
    JMenuItem Programm = new JMenuItem("Programm");
    file.add(Author);
    file.add(Programm);
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю проблема здесь

```
  incriptScroll.getViewport().add(inputText);
  incriptScroll = new 

  JScrollPane(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
  JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
  incriptScroll.setBounds(550,45,20,50);
```

в первой строке этого куска вы пытаетесь в incriptScroll добавить панель (здесь программа должена падать с NullPointerException ), а после вы инициализируете incriptScroll.

Если поменять эти строки местами то должно работать

```
  incriptScroll = new 
  JScrollPane(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
  JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
  incriptScroll.setBounds(550,45,20,50);
  incriptScroll.getViewport().add(inputText);
```